# retrieving data from a Sharepoint Person column on PowerApp

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-formula, dataverse

i have a powerapp with a gallery showing users stored in a sharepoint list inside a Person column named User.

I have no problem in showing the users, for instance, in my gallery i can use ThisItem.User.DisplayName with no problem, but when i want to make a search filtered on some user data it doesnt work. If i try filtering using another column such as "city" it works, so it seems an error due to the type of the data that the Person column output.

this is the code i want to apply to my gallery

```
search(MyList,searchbar.text,User.DisplayName)
```

the error says "Name isn't valid. 'User' isn't recognized."
how to fix this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try User().FullName

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.